# Images not visible on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, image, icons

I hava the following issue - my app is working well on all devices I have, but I have just tried it on Galaxy S3 and I am surprised to see, that all images are... gone. The only image, that is still visible, is the app icon image. On the S3 I have downloaded the app from th market.. and as mentioned - on the other devices it works as expected. The images are statically loaded in xml in image views... nothing fancy...

Any idea what could cause such behavior?

This is the app id in market, if needed (NOT intended to be app advertisement!):
Com.rts.android.tictactoe3d

Thank you!

Comment: I installed it on my GS3 and everything seemed to be in order. Try reinstalling it?

Comment: Tried 2 or 3 times, same thing... it seems to run just fine on HTC Desire, Sony tablet S, Galaxy S2 and the emulator... only at my S3 all icons are gone for all my games... I am slowly running out of ideas...

Comment: Try going to your application manager and clearing any data and cache

Comment: Just tried it... nothing changed...

Comment: I now see in the log something about SpannableStringBuilder that should not have zero length... but without any trace, nothing... will google it tomorow...

Comment: Ok, it seems like this thing with the SpannableStringBuilder has nothing to do with my apps... any other suggestions or ideas why an app is unable to load the images on Galaxy S3?

Comment: Got firmware update today and since then the icons are displayed correctly without app reinstall.
Anyway, thanks for the support, Adam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that GIF image format is not entirely supported in some Android versions, for more information you could take a look at the thread below and a big THANK YOU to Rich for solving the issue!

[Images not loading on Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146250/images-not-loading-on-galaxy-s3)

Answer (score 0):

This was a wired issue, it dissipated after I have updated my S3 to the latest firmware. Before that nothing really helped, I have tried to cleanup the application data, uninstall/reinstall, more the app to the SD or back to phone - same behavior.