# Images not loading on Galaxy S3

Tags: android, image

I am facing a weird issue, which is already driving me crazy, so ANY help is most welcome and appreciated.

I have created an Android application, which is working quite fine on all kinds of phones and tablets, but on some Galaxy S3 devices, the images are not loaded at all.

Here are the facts, both from myself and information that I gathered from the complaining users of the app:

- all images are packaged in the application, in the drawable folder, so accessible from all resolutions
- the images are referenced either by `mypackage.R.drawable.image_id`, or directly via `@drawable/image_id` in the XML
- the images are semi-transparent and are stored in `.gif` format
- there are about 40 images altogether, each is 25x25 pixels, the "largest" is 1.25Kb
- for now I have got only complaints from S3 owners
- the issue occurs on the standard OS and not on custom roms (at least I have no info about custom roms)
- at least one S3 owner, who is facing the issue, claims that his phone is updated to the latest Android version
- on many S3 devices the issue is not reproducible and the application works as designed
- I am testing my apps on S2, S3, HTC Desire, Sony tablet S and of course the emulator - on all those I am not able to reproduce the issue
- I am using `FrameLayout`, where the main drawing area takes the whole space, the controls (where the images are used) are packed in a `LinearLayout`, which is floating above

Here is a link to the application on the market:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rts.android.spacesim&feature=search_result

This is NOT intended as some weird way to promote my app, if you are an S3 owner and decide to check if the issue is reproducible on your device, please write a comment here if it is and if not - what do you observe.

**My questions are:**

- have anyone observed such an issue?
- any ideas how to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following links suggest that GIF support might be broken again on 4.1, which most Galaxy S3's are running if I'm not mistaken.  My personal phone is a Galaxy S3 at the moment, and I have 4.1.1 on it

[GIF doesn't display on Samsung Galaxy Note 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149852/gif-doesnt-display-on-samsung-galaxy-note-2)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

Why not use png?

Comment: The code.google.com thread is quite old and I can't see it mentions GIF's in general (only animated). Did you link the right issue?

Comment: I think the second link is just a hint, that the gif support could be faulty, as it really is! I have changed all my images to PNG and I have one confirmation, that the issue is resolved!

Thanks A LOT, Rich!!

Comment: @MerlinBG Just tested on four devices including a Galaxy S2 running 4.1.2 (CM 10) and Galaxy S3 running 4.1.1.  Everything looks good to me

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! :)
Never thought, that gif would not be supported... I am going to redo all images for all my apps to be png now.