# PNGs using more memory than GIFs

Tags: android, image, png, gif, formats

I have created an Android app which used a lot of GIFs.  I got some feedback that images were not being displayed on the Galaxy S III and I used this post to realize that my GIFs were the problem: [Images not loading on Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146250/images-not-loading-on-galaxy-s3).

But I am left with a concern.  I borrowed some code from a post to give me how much memory I am using.  When I am using GIFs I get values like this:

```
I/memory  (  547): App Memory: Pss=12.15 MB
I/memory  (  547): Private=10.52 MB
I/memory  (  547): Shared=8.47 MB
```

When I switch to PNGs I am getting values like this:

```
I/memory  (  547): App Memory: Pss=21.33 MB
I/memory  (  547): Private=20.18 MB
I/memory  (  547): Shared=14.02 MB
```

Why is the memory use so much higher when using PNGs?

I have 110 images, ranging in size from about 75x75 to 1048x907 (1KB to 148KB). The total size of the GIFs is 1.39MB and the total size of the PNGs = 1.48MB. As for compression, I am using Paint.NET to save them and using 'auto-detect' for the Bit Depth.

Edit: I went back and looked and most of the images are saved as 8-bit, 256 color.

The fact that the GIFs takes less disk space I guess is the part that is confusing. It seems like Android should handle PNGs with more ease.

I am using surface view and calling canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: Well, there's the typical question of image size and resolution. Assuming they're the same, PNG images can support 32 bit images with transparency. Do you know what bitness your PNG images are? From what I know, I think the lowest PNG (8 bit) should be equivalent to a GIF.

Comment: What about comparing the plain image sizes (files), before looking at the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

How big are your images? The two seem to vary... If the images are small, say 10px x 10px then GIF usually comes out smaller. For bigger images PNG is (almost?) always a smaller file size.

In general I always use PNG for assets that matter, say like a player in a game, a button etc. And JPEG for backgrounds etc.

How are you compressing your PNG's? If at all?

Comment: I have 110 images, ranging in size from about 75x75 to 1048x907 (1KB to 148KB).  The total size of the GIFs is 1.39MB and the total size of the PNGs = 1.48MB.  As for compression, I am using Paint.NET to save them and using 'auto-detect' for the Bit Depth.

Comment: The fact that the GIFs takes less disk space I guess is the part that is confusing. It seems like Android should handle PNGs with more ease.

Comment: I am using surface view and calling canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: Try making the PNG images paletted (256 colors) -only then you can compare with GIF. Or save it with PNGOUT (eg, via Irfanview)